# calculating and keeping in the dataset only mean values of specific rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

i am working with a big dataset where I have some observations with more measures and I would like to change the dataset in the way that for the observations with more values I keep only the mean.

I am adding a very small replicable example to show what I would like to do:

`df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Tina", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"), n = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 32, 76,51,20,34))`

Here, I would like to keep the same data frame but instead of having three values for Ben and Joe, I would like to keep only the mean value of the three observations... this is a small example but I have a big data frame, could it be done with a function that can be applied to a bigger dataset?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `df |> group_by(Name) |> summarize(n = mean(n))` using functions from the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get the mean values of Ben and Joe using `group_by` and `summarise` and after that add the remaining names using `bind_rows` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Tina", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"), n = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 32, 76,51,20,34))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Name %in% c("Ben", "Joe"))  %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(n = mean(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(!(Name %in% c("Ben", "Joe"))))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   Name      n
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Ben    38.7
#> 2 Joe    35  
#> 3 Jon    23  
#> 4 Bill   41  
#> 5 Maria  32  
#> 6 Tina   76
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` in the `summarize` call. I'm going to rename your original `n` variable to  `n_val` to avoid confusion with the call the function `n()` which counts the number of rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Tina", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"), 
  n_val = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 32, 76,51,20,34)
)

df |> 
  group_by(Name) |> 
  summarize(n_val = ifelse(n() > 1, mean(n_val), n_val))
```

This allows you to adjust the threshold without knowing a priori which names to filter on.

Comment: great thanks! if I want to do it for many columns should I do it with a for loop?

Comment: Check out `dplyr::across` and the `vignette("colwise")`